# Error: cannot dynamically allocate this value type object on native heap

Tags: c++-cli, clr

I am trying to create an instance of `System::DateTime`on-the-fly and assign it to `System::DateTime gDate` in case user uses 'P' argument. But, I get the error shown following the code snippet.

```
case 'P':
  gDate=new DateTime(std::stoi(year), std::stoi(month), std::stoi(day));            
  cout << "Persian Date is: " << pDate.GetDayOfMonth(gDate) << "/" <<
       pDate.GetMonth (gDate) << "/" << pDate.GetYear(gDate) << endl;
  break;
```

> Error C3255   'System::DateTime': cannot dynamically allocate this value
>   type object on native heap

What causes the error and how should I prevent it?

Update:
I probably should have said in the first place, I tried also the following definition:

```
DateTime gDate(std::stoi(year), std::stoi(month), std::stoi(day));
```

But, I received the error, `Error   C2360   initialization of 'gDate' is skipped by 'case' label`

Comment: Most of the stuff that comes back from the CLI/CLR libraries require CLI/CLR semantics and garbage collection when used as a pointer.

Comment: Removed C++ tag. This is C++/CLI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need gDate to be a pointer, and you almost certainly do not, try:

```
 case 'P':
     {
         DateTime gDate(std::stoi(year), std::stoi(month), std::stoi(day));          
         cout << "Persian Date is: " << pDate.GetDayOfMonth(gDate) << "/" <<
                  pDate.GetMonth (gDate) << "/" << pDate.GetYear(gDate) << endl;
     }
     break;
```

The braces establish a scope for gDate, ensuring deletion when the program exits the braces.

CLI/CLR C++ is a different beast from C++ and has some different semantics.

CLI/C++ has added a concepts of `value` and `ref` structs and classes. These are objects with automatic lifetime control. The .Net runtime, not the programmer, decides when they live and die, and this requires different syntax.

Those tagged `value` are intended to be used as one would use a Plain Old Datatype like an int or a double. Create 'em as a temporary, use them, and let the stack or whatever other method of managing temporary variables is in use take care of the clean-up. You can point to them, but it is not recommended.

`ref` structs and classes are designed with referenced use in mind and are open game for pointers, so long as they are garbage collected pointers.

System::DateTime is a value struct, so what follows strays from its recommended use. As a pointer, System::DateTime must either be used as a garbage collected pointer with `^` in place of `*` and allocated with `gcnew` in place of `new` or as a variable with a defined scope.

If gDate must be a pointer, it must be defined

```
DateTime ^ gDate;
```

And allocating it requires

```
gDate = gcnew DateTime(std::stoi(year), std::stoi(month), std::stoi(day));
```

When there are no further references to this allocated object, gDate and any copies of gDate have gone out of scope, the .Net runtime's garbage collector will destroy it.

Comment: When I use the normal definition of `DateTime gDate([parameters...])`, I get the error "Initialization of gDate is skipped by 'case' label".

Comment: The braces are mandatory. Can't have a scoped variable without defining the scope.

Comment: Don't use `gcnew` with `DateTime`, as it's a *value type*. If you use `gcnew` you're creating a boxed value (that is, a managed reference tracking a value type), which is not what you want 99.99% of the time and simply a waste of resources. Just use `DateTime` on the stack, and use copy semantics - the last snippet in this answer is the correct way to do this.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Good points. Will edit to hammer this home.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb709xx0.aspx), you can create `DateTime` on the stack, but not on the heap.

Try like this:

```
DateTime gDate(std::stoi(year), std::stoi(month), std::stoi(day));          
cout << "Persian Date is: " << pDate.GetDayOfMonth(gDate) << "/" <<
     pDate.GetMonth (gDate) << "/" << pDate.GetYear(gDate) << endl;
break;
```

alternatively, you can use `gcnew` to allocate managed memory:

```
DateTime^ gDate = gcnew DateTime(std::stoi(year), std::stoi(month), std::stoi(day));
```